# Which logging library should I use for Go in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I find tw kind of go library for GAE：

1. "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
2. "cloud.google.com/go/logging"

Which one should I use ?
By the way I use both logging library in my app.
In local dev mode , I can see log like this.

```
2019/01/08 06:57:34 INFO: Search keyword="test" idOnly=bool
2019/01/08 06:57:34 INFO: Search:"test"
```

But when I deploy to production GAE, I cannot see any log.

No matter using stackdriver by

```
resource.type="gae_app" resource.labels.module_id="default"
```

Or gcloud command

```
 gcloud app logs tail -s default
```

Comment: What version of Go are you using? (check the output of the command `go version`)

Comment: My go version go111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the logs to appear in Stackdriver Logging, the correct approach would be to use the ["google.golang.org/appengine/log" package](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/log).

However, as per the [documentation on the Go1.11 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences), it is recommended [not to use the App Engine specific API's and use the Google Cloud client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences#migrating-appengine-sdk).

In regards to logging, this means that instead of using "google.golang.org/appengine/log", the recommended approach is to use the ["log" package](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) instead. An example:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: go111
```

**hello.go**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)

        port := os.Getenv("PORT")
        if port == "" {
                port = "8080"
        }

        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Create the log and write it
        log.Printf("Hello world!")
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Log written in Stackdriver!")
}
```

This log will appear in Stackdriver Logging under:

```
resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.module_id="default"
logName="projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>/logs/stderr"
```

Or by selecting `stderr` in the log filter drop down list.

However, if you wish, you can still use the "google.golang.org/appengine/log" package, but you will have to add the "google.golang.org/appengine" package as well, and add the `appengine.Main()` entrypoint in the `main()` function.

Comment: Actually, I have use  "google.golang.org/appengine/log" package with  appengine.Main() entrypoint in the main() function. I will try to use "log" .

Comment: I have another question why Instead of using the App Engine Search API, host any full-text search database such as ElasticSearch on Compute Engine and access it from your service ? App Engine Search API will deprecate ?

Comment: The reason for this is because the App Engine Search API currently is only available in the Python2.7, Java 8 and Go 1.9 runtimes (and only in App Engine Standard).

Comment: Actually, I use Go 1.11 runtimes with appengine.Main() , and I can use  App Engine Search API. But still can not see log on stackdriver. I will try go back to 1.9

Comment: It's strange that your logs don't show up. Maybe you are surpassing some of the [Stackdriver Logging quotas](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas)?

Comment: Finally , I found my GAE be exclude from stackdrive. Now I can see my log . Thanks

Comment: But by using Go's standard log library there is no way to differentiate log levels such as Critical, Error, Warning, Info and Debug.

Writing a service using cloud.google.com/go/logging locks you into using GAE. Later if we wish to switch to a GCE or Kubernetes each have their own conventions for logging.

I wish there were a way to prefix stdout and stderr logging to denote the log level, so it can be filtered for in the StackDriver logs viewer. Even better would be a standard logging methodology across all platforms.

Comment: @AndyFusniak I partially resolved this issue by creating a util package for my project that wraps the basic functions of the `google.golang.org/appengine/log` package, and it just prefixes all the logs with a `- DEBUG -`, `- ERROR -` or `- INFO -`. I know it's an old issue, but it's maybe helpful for someone

Answer (score 2):

You could also go the [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) route, where you don't depend on the above client libraries.

```
// Entry defines a log entry.
type Entry struct {
    Message  string `json:"message"`
    Severity string `json:"severity,omitempty"`
    Trace    string `json:"logging.googleapis.com/trace,omitempty"`

    // Cloud Log Viewer allows filtering and display of this as `jsonPayload.component`.
    Component string `json:"component,omitempty"`
}

// String renders an entry structure to the JSON format expected by Cloud Logging.
func (e Entry) String() string {
    if e.Severity == "" {
        e.Severity = "INFO"
    }
    out, err := json.Marshal(e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("json.Marshal: %v", err)
    }
    return string(out)
}
```

and then log using the built-in `log` package:

```
log.Println(Entry{
        Severity:  "NOTICE",
        Message:   "This is the default display field.",
        Component: "arbitrary-property",
        Trace:     trace,
    })
```

Here is a full example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/run/logging-manual/main.go

Comment: I tried this and in the Google App Engine logs it wasn't assigned the proper severity level, just came through as JSON in default severity.